# What is the purpose of the mezuzah on the entrance to Sha'ar Tziyon?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, yerushalayim-jerusalem, cities

It's been a while since I visited the Old City in Jerusalem. I recall that there is a giant mezuzah on the sidewall of the Zion Gate. I don't recall if all the Jerusalem gates have a mezuzah.

I'm curious as to why that mezuzah is needed? Perhaps, at some point, people actually did live in the wall itself? (See, e.g. Rahav who lived in the wall of Jericho.) However, the gate is a public entrance, and I understand that it is up to an individual to place the mezuzah on the home that he lives in, i.e. not a public place where no-one lives e.g. a Beth hakneset (Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea 286,3).

Or, maybe, because there are people living in the confines of the Old City, the gate acts as a communal entrance to all the other houses, there?

In short, does a gated walled city require a mezuzah at all? If not, why does that gate have a mezuzah, or is it just "decorative"?

Comment: You missed the last word of Shema. The verse isn't וכתבתם על מזוזת ביתך.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ach!!! I can't believe I missed that!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rambam Mezuza 6,8

> אחד שערי חצרות ואחד שערי מבואות ואחד שערי מדינות ועיירות הכל חייבים במזוזה שהרי הבתים החייבין במזוזה פתוחין לתוכן
>   Gates of courtyards, cul de sacs, countries and cities need a Mezuza as the houses which need Mezuzas open up to those gates (i.e the only way out of that enclosed city/courtyard from ones house is through one of those gates.)

Kesef Mishna quotes Yuma 11a with Rahi as source and parameter which type of gate requires a Mezuza:
When the gate of the city is part of the wall that surrounds the house, the outer gate is like the outer entrance of the house as **One can only go into the house via one of the gates as the wall/forest/mountains surrounds it**

> ברייתא שם (יומא דף י"א) אחד שערי בתים ואחד שערי חצרות ואחד שערי מדינות ואחד שערי עיירות חייבין במזוזה ופירש"י שערי מדינות יש מדינה מוקפת הרים ויערים בכמה פרסאות **ואין יוצאין ממנה אלא דרך שערים**

On a gate of a Ghetto of a non Jewish town however since it is a danger for jews, or in a warehouse with many Goyim workers who act degrading towards the Mezzuza or prone to steal them one is exempt. Maase Rokeach ibid:

> כתבו ז"ל **דהיכא שיש לחוש לסכנה מפני הגוים פטורים** וכדאיתא ביומא שם ובשו"ת באר שבע סימן י"ג פטר מטעם זה גם פתחי הגיטו"ס שלנו והביאו הרב כנסת הגדולה יו"ד שם וגדולה מזו כתב הרב ב"ח הביאו הש"ך שם דישראל החוכר חכירות מן השר למכור יין שרף או שכר **והגוים ממלאים הבית בכל יום ורגילין ליקח מזוזות ונוהגים בהם מנהג בזיון שאין לעשות מזוזה**